Why is $\mathrm dA_{\perp} = \mathrm dA\cos(\theta)$?
Why is $\mathrm dA_{\perp}=\mathrm dA\cos(\theta)$ where $\mathrm dA_\perp$ denotes the component of the area $\mathrm dA$ normal to a line making an angle $\theta$ with its normal?
I'm sure there's an easy fix to this, but I can't seem to find it. Let $\mathrm dA$ be a tiny patch of area on an arbitrary surface. Let $\mathrm dA_{\perp}$ be the part of this area that is parallel to the vector field. So, this would be $\mathrm dA = A_2$ and $\mathrm dA_{\perp} = A_n$ in the below image.

Now, why is $\mathrm dA_{\perp}=\mathrm dA
\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector field and the normal component to the surface? From the above image, the diameter of $\mathrm dA_{\perp}$ is equal to the diameter of $\mathrm dA$ times $\cos(\theta)$. From this, shouldn't it follow that:
$$\mathrm dA_{\perp}=\frac{\pi d_{\perp}^2}{4}=\frac{\pi (d\cos(\theta))^2}{4}=\frac{\pi d^2\cos^2(\theta)}{4}=\mathrm dA\cos^2(\theta)$$
What am I missing?

Area is a vector quantity, so we can take its projection in a particular direction, just like any other vector.

@MathGuy Makes sense. Also, could you point out how my reasoning was fallacious?

Use \ for trig functions, logs, etc. for better appearance of the functions,

The elementary area $\mathrm dA$ is an ellipse if $\mathrm dA_\perp$ is a circle as you can't have a circle projected in a particular direction to yield another circle.

This is a really good question, now I realize I had taken area as a vector for granted.

The area of ellipse is just a limit of sums of areas of rectangles. The $\cos \theta$ relation is obvious for rectangular shapes, and if you take their sum and take a limit, $\cos\theta$ will be a constant during the limit

Consider two rectangular strips with a dihedral angle $\theta$ between them. See this image. Now the area of the upper strip is $A = l \times b$. Now consider the side view of the image. We can see that the length of the bottom strip is $l \cos \theta$. Hence the area $A_{\perp} = l \cos \theta \times b = A \cos \theta$. Now you can generalise this to any shape.

relevant 3b1b video
